# How to save and retrieve multiple NSDictionaries in a file

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsfilemanager

I want to store my data in document directory which is in multiple dictionaries.

Is there any way to store and retrieve them separately in a single file and also is it possible to update part of the file?

Currently i am saving them under a single array on the whole and retrieving on the whole.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there any way to store and retrieve them separately in a single file**

Sure. Create a dictionary of `NSDictionary` instances and write that to a file.

> **Is it possible to update part of the file?**

If you are committed to persisting your object model in this way, then you will have to read in your data set.  Modify it, then write it back to disk.  This may be desirable, or it may not be, depending on how large your data set is among other factors.

Answer (score 0):

To store and retrieve your dictionaries as individual entities from a single file would require you to re-invent some of the concept typically built into a database.  If that's really a requirement, look at saving your dictionaries to table rows in sqlite or converting them to custom objects and using Core Data.